# Vertical align with flex-box and flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Currently my HTML is displaying like this:
[image: Current State]
I want it to display like this:
[image]

The buttons need to be vertically aligned with the text using flex-box, or another method that does not require padding, margin (margin:auto is fine), or offsets.

http://codepen.io/simply-simpy/pen/vKpAYN

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/about.html">about</a>
    <button>+</button>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/level-2.html">Level 2 nav item</a>
            <button>+</button>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 .nav {
    width: 300px;
  }
  button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  ul > ul li{
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  ul > ul > ul li {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height: 3;
  }
  a {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group `button` and `a` in one `div` and use `display: flex` on that div with `align-items: center` to vertically center items.

```css
.nav {
  width: 300px;
}
button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul > ul li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
ul > ul > ul li {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
li {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
a {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: block;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="/about.html">about</a>
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="/level-2.html">Level 2 nav item</a>
          <button>+</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/level-3.html">Level 3 nav item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```